# Possible to get Video duration through metadata?

Tags: spservices, metadata, video

Is it possible to access video metadata such as duration, or other valuable pieces of information? Possible through SPServices?

I currently have a lot of videos, and trying to build a sorting feature through them. Without going through and entering in the data in a custom column.

Edit: Right now I'm in the process of building a video gallery page without access to VS or the server, so please bare with me.

I use SPServices to call a folder that has the videos. I then parse through the files and create silverlight video objects on the page (rather than use webparts). So far everything works out pretty well in terms of displaying the videos.

The difficulty comes when creating more customization. Since it appears that the only parameters I can use for silverlight player is title, filepath, preview image.

Videos are silverlight compatible. Made in through Microsoft's expression based encoders.

EDIT: For now. I've created a column in my document list, and I'm entering the duration manually. This is a temporary solution. But I predict this will get out of hand quickly in the future.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE, Chris! You have a nice question there. I think you can get a better and more accurate answer if you provide a little more detail on what type of video content you got. File format, how the videos are produced, tools used and other meta info of interest. Nice to see you here!

Comment: Thanks. Edits have been made. Silverlight compatible videos are made through expressions. I can read metadata properties through normal file browser just fine.